# How to get the latest version of dedicated typing package

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

In a sample project when i try typings install for below typings.js I get warning. how do we get the latest version number and what is the number after + symbole

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

> typings WARN deprecated 10/7/2016:
>   "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046" is deprecated (updated,
>   replaced or removed) typings WARN deprecated 10/4/2016:
>   "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255" is deprecated (updated,
>   replaced or removed) typings WARN deprecated 9/14/2016:
>   "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759" is deprecated (updated,
>   replaced or removed)
>
> +-- core-js (global)
>   +-- jasmine (global) `-- node (global)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Skip the version postfix `#xxxxxxx` will install the latest ones:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine",
    "node": "registry:dt/node"
  }
}
```

Use `typings info dt~<package> --version` to find the version of a dt package:

```
> typings info dt~node --versions                                                       
TAG                    VERSION DESCRIPTION COMPILER LOCATION                                                                                             UPDATED                                                                       
6.0.0+20161006230116   6.0.0                        github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts#38f26299ffa6ed4898e1dad4936b4ac6c6c66096       2016-10-06T23:01:16.000Z
0.12.0+20160906152630  0.12.0                       github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node-0.12.d.ts#03f3ca4333161dea8c5fa0ba47d55b02da92d40d  2016-09-06T15:26:30.000Z
0.11.13+20160906152630 0.11.13                      github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node-0.11.d.ts#03f3ca4333161dea8c5fa0ba47d55b02da92d40d  2016-09-06T15:26:30.000Z
0.10.1+20160906152630  0.10.1                       github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node-0.10.d.ts#03f3ca4333161dea8c5fa0ba47d55b02da92d40d  2016-09-06T15:26:30.000Z
0.8.8+20160906152630   0.8.8                        github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node-0.8.8.d.ts#03f3ca4333161dea8c5fa0ba47d55b02da92d40d 2016-09-06T15:26:30.000Z
```